# Why my insertBefore() only adding 1 element?

Tags: html, jquery

I have a function that when the button clicked, the card is showing after the 1st card. But when I am clicking again the button it is not working and there is no error showing in console.

**

```js
$(function() {
    var $budget = $('<div class="card-single"> <div class="card-body"> <span class="fas fa-coins"></span> <div> <h5>{{ date_posted }}</h5> <h4>$30,659.45</h4> </div> </div> <div class="card-footer"> <a href="">Add Expenses</a> </div> </div>')

    $('.add-budget').on('click', function() {
        $budget.insertBefore('.card-single:last');
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<main>
            <div class="head">
                <h2 class="dash-title">Budgets</h2>
                <button class="add-budget">Add Budget</button>
            </div>

            <div class="dash-cards">
                <div class="card-single">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <span class="fas fa-coins"></span>
                        <div>
                            <h5>{{ date_posted }}</h5>
                            <h4>$30,659.45</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-footer">
                        <a href="">Add Expenses</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
```

**

I tried using before(), prependTo(), appendTo(), and insertAfter() but it has a same output.

Answer (score 0):

You only ever created one `.card-single` element, in `$budget` - whenever the button is clicked, the single element will be inserted to the new location *and removed from its previous location* if there is any. Create the element inside the handler instead.

```js
$('.add-budget').on('click', function() {

  var $budget = $('<div class="card-single"> <div class="card-body"> <span class="fas fa-coins"></span> <div> <h5>{{ date_posted }}</h5> <h4>$30,659.45</h4> </div> </div> <div class="card-footer"> <a href="">Add Expenses</a> </div> </div>')
  $budget.insertBefore('.card-single:last');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <div class="head">
    <h2 class="dash-title">Budgets</h2>
    <button class="add-budget">Add Budget</button>
  </div>

  <div class="dash-cards">
    <div class="card-single">
      <div class="card-body">
        <span class="fas fa-coins"></span>
        <div>
          <h5>{{ date_posted }}</h5>
          <h4>$30,659.45</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card-footer">
        <a href="">Add Expenses</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```