# Is there a way to permanently add the elements added using jquery?

Tags: jquery, flask

I have [Why my insertBefore() only adding 1 element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66416664/why-my-insertbefore-only-adding-1-element) this function and I am using flask and flask-sqlalchemy as my backend. Is there some way how can I permanently add the elements added in jquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a way to do that: Specifically by sending an AJAX req to some route that you've created, with some data ( WHATEVER DYNAMIC DATA YOU MADE FOR YOUR JQUERY ELEMENT ).
Then, in that route handler, do some logic to keep that data with you. Next time you load the browser, it will show up

Comment: does this method can affect processing time or performance of my web app?

Comment: Well, AJAX requests are made while the user is 'on the page'. It will process without the user knowing about it. So it doesn't affect processing time (the time taken for the webpage to load). Performance time, I'll have to look it up :)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add permanently elements using jquery. When you add an element using jquery it's  keep on the web page until browser is not refreshed.

Comment: Oh I see. then I will use jinja instead. Thank you!